# Printing in TwoLineListView in android

Tags: java, android, textview

I wonder if it is possible to print in TwoLineListView like in TextEdit? For example if I want to print some word in line1 and translation in line2? Is there anything like twolinedtextview.add("word,"translation"); ? I need my text to appear in listview when i press the button.

Comment: http://www.codercorp.com/blog/android/android-two-line-listview-with-custom-data.html

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you are using `default ArrayAdapter` with the ListView, then you can use **ONLY ONE TextView.**

**2.** But you can **very well do this** with the help of `Custom adapter` by using `BaseAdapter` or 
       `ArrayAdapter`..

**See this link for an easy tutorial:**

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

you can subclass `ArrayAdapter` class, override `getView()`, and construct your rows yourself. The `getView()` method is responsible for returning a `View`, representing the row for the supplied position in the adapter data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to extend `ArrayAdapter` (like the others suggested), you can always use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)

Here's a short [tutorial](http://tekeye.biz/2012/two-line-lists-in-android) about using it for 2 line list.